# Character Count Not Working on 2nd Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I'm building a simple Welcome page that has a Name & Age text input field.  I was able to successfully limit the character input count on the name field, but using the same logic on the age field has not worked at all.  Thoughts?

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    nameTextField.delegate = self
    ageTextField.delegate = self
    
}


// Character Count Code UITextField
func textField(_ nameTextField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // get the current text, or use an empty string if that failed
    let currentText = nameTextField.text ?? ""

    // attempt to read the range they are trying to change, or exit if we can't
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

    // add their new text to the existing text
    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

    // make sure the result is under # characters
    return updatedText.count <= 30
}

func textField2(_ ageTextField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range2: NSRange, replacementString string2: String) -> Bool {
    // get the current text, or use an empty string if that failed
    let currentText2 = ageTextField.text ?? ""

    // attempt to read the range they are trying to change, or exit if we can't
    guard let stringRange2 = Range(range2, in: currentText2) else { return false }

    // add their new text to the existing text
    let updatedText2 = currentText2.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange2, with: string2)

    // make sure the result is under # characters
    return updatedText2.count <= 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate method has a specific signature (`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`) that is called by the system. Your first function uses that pattern.

Your second one, currently, does not, since you've named it `textField2` -- the system has no reason to know to call something starting with that prefix.

Instead, you should probably use a single function and then have it behave differently based on which `UITextField` is sent in to the first parameter:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == nameTextField {
      //content
    }
    if textField == ageTextField {
      //content
    }
}
```

This could obviously be an `else if`, or even just an `else` if you stay limited to 2 text fields. Within the `if` block, you could either call out to a separate, specialized function, or keep all of your logic within the `if` block.

Example with `switch`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    switch textfield {
    case nameTextField:
      //content
    case ageTextField:
      //content
    default:
      return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this is on the right track... but i'm new to functions - when I move the code inside the "if textField..." statement - i get this error at the end of the function.  How would I correctly close the function?   Error = "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'"

Comment: You'd have to return a default value if neither `if` block were hit (which it shouldn't...). So, you could, for example, just add `return true` at the end of the function outside of both `if` blocks.

Comment: better to use a switch

Comment: @LeoDabus probably a good idea. Edited to include an example with `switch`